# How do I get back my character that was mysteriously deleted?

Tags: terraria

I had a great character in *Terraria*, but something happened one night where I got an error code 105501110, when I got into the game my character was somehow deleted.

What do I do to get my character back?

Comment: What said error 105501110, your files or terraria?

Answer (score 3):

Terraria has game save files in the documents folder of current user. Check if there is still a save file remaining.

Answer (score 0):

Was this on mobile? if it was then it's probably because you somehow downgraded the apk or it thinks you downgrade. the same happened to me on mobile.
now unless you have root you can go fetch the player file and take it out, reload the game, then close the game and put it back in, then it should be fixed